# How to map a field to a differently named column in EF Core 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to map a field from an entity to a column in a table.  I want the column to have a different name to the field.

Entity class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    private string _dynamicallyCreatedValue;
}
```

entity configuration:

```
    builder.Property<string>("MyColumnName")
           .HasField("_dynamicallyCreatedValue);
```

migration exception:
*The specified field '_dynamicallyCreatedValue' cannot be used for the property 'MyColumnName' because it does not match the property name. Entity type properties that aren't associated with a CLR property must match the field name exactly.*

Also tried:

```
builder.Property<string>("_dynamicallyCreatedValue")
       .HasField("_dynamicallyCreatedValue")
       .HasColumnName("MyColumnName");
```

migration exception:
*The property '_dynamicallyCreatedValue' cannot be added to the type 'MyEntity' because no property type was specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property, the property type must be specified.*

This works:

```
    builder.Property<string>("_dynamicallyCreatedValue");
```

but then I don't get the column name I require.

Comment: What about: `.Property<string>("_dynamicallyCreatedValue").HasColumnName("MyColumnName")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
builder
    .Property<string>("_dynamicallyCreatedValue") // Name of field
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field) // Access mode type
    .HasColumnName("MyColumnName"); // Db column name
```

Comment: I must have tried every combination except this one.  Thanks

Comment: In EF Core  for .NET 8, `Property` did not exist on `builder` . Instead if used `builder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property<string>(...` and the rest was the same.